# How to Toggle an Image to a Text in a ListView onClick

Tags: listview, android-fragments, arraylist, android-imageview, textview, android

I have an Array in the fragment which displays Image in the left of the list and two textviews and the class also plays an audio when a list item is selected..

WordFragment.java

```
final ArrayList<Word> words = new ArrayList<Word>();
words.add(new Word(R.string.letter_a, R.string.letter_a,
        R.drawable.number_one, R.raw.letter_audio_a));
words.add(new Word(R.string.letter_b, R.string.letter_b,
        R.drawable.number_two, R.raw.letter_audio_b));
```

How do I toggle the Image `R.drawable.number_one` in the ListView to the Text `R.string.letter_a` onClick of the Image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution..

I just added another String Variable `R.string.hindi_letter_a` in my `Word Class` and updated my fragment as

```
final ArrayList<Word> words = new ArrayList<Word>();
words.add(new Word(R.string.letter_a,R.drawable.number_one, R.raw.letter_audio_a, R.string.hindi_letter_a));
words.add(new Word(R.string.letter_b,R.drawable.number_two, R.raw.letter_audio_b, R.string.hindi_letter_b));
```

Now all i did was to hide the string `R.string.hindi_letter_a` on startup and show the text `R.string.hindi_letter_a`  onClick of the ImageView

This way i toggled the Image `R.drawable.number_one` in the ListView to the Text `R.string.hindi_letter_a` onClick of the Image?